# AWS .NET SDK Multipart File Upload from Http

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I've implemented a .ashx handler which receives chunked upload parts of a file from the client. Previously I first stored the files in a temp folder before uploading them to AWS. 
As the files have become quite big, I'd like to skip the temp folder part and upload them directly to AWS using the MultiPart requests.

It looks fine so far, but I can't find an overload which accepts either the HttpPostedFile or Stream for the upload..

I something like the following possible?

```
        // Create request to upload a part.
        UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
            .WithBucketName(myBucket)
            .WithKey(myKey)
            .WithUploadId(myUploadId)                
            .WithPartNumber(partNumber)
            .WithInputStream(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WithInputStream will return s3 request instead of UploadPartRequest
so just cast the return type to UploadPartRequest

```
// Create request to upload a part.
        UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
            .WithBucketName(myBucket)
            .WithKey(myKey)
            .WithUploadId(myUploadId)                
            .WithPartNumber(partNumber);

uploadRequest = (UploadPartRequest)uploadRequest.WithInputStream(ftiObject.sourceStream);
```

this works for me

Answer (score 2):

```
UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
        .WithBucketName(myBucket)
        .WithKey(myKey)
        .WithUploadId(myUploadId)                
        .WithPartNumber(partNumber)
        .WithInputStream(stream) as UploadPartRequest;
```

This is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Just set the Input Stream via the Property:

```
            // Create request to upload a part.
            UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                .WithBucketName(myBucket)
                .WithKey(myKey)
                .WithUploadId(UploadId)
                .WithPartNumber(PartNumber)
                .WithPartSize(inputStream.Length)
                .WithFilePosition(FilePosition);

            uploadRequest.InputStream = inputStream;
```